# TabItem Output is not working for R Shinydashboard

Tags: r, web-applications, shiny, shinydashboard, tabitem

I am trying to build a simple app using Shinydashboard. One of the tabitems ("Raw Data") does not display anything and neither the page changes when clicked on it. I have cross-checked the syntax and the code is running fine. Don't understand what's wrong.

**Ui.R-**

```
header = dashboardHeader(title="COVID-19 Tracker")

sidebar =   dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE,
                   sidebarMenu(menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "Dashboard",icon = icon("globe")),
                               menuItem("Raw Data", tabName = "Raw Data", icon = icon("database")),
                               menuItem("Graphs",tabName = "Graphs", icon = icon("chart-bar"))
                               ))
body =  dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "Dashboard",
                   fluidRow(valueBox(10*3, "Cases", width = 4), 
                            valueBoxOutput("Recovered", width = 4), 
                            valueBoxOutput("Deaths", width = 4)
                            )
                   ),
    tabItem(tabName = "Raw Data", h2("Raw Data has been loaded!")
                   ),
    tabItem(tabName = "Graphs",fluidRow(
             column(
               width=4, 
               selectizeInput(
                 "country", label=h5("Country"), choices=NULL, width="100%")
             ),
             column(
               width=4, 
               selectizeInput(
                 "state", label=h5("State"), choices=NULL, width="100%")
             ),
             column(
               width=4, 
               checkboxGroupInput(
                 "metrics", label=h5("Selected Metrics"), 
                 choices=c("Confirmed", "Deaths", "Recovered"), 
                 selected=c("Confirmed", "Deaths", "Recovered"), 
                 width="100%")
             )
           ),
           fluidRow(
             plotlyOutput("dailyMetrics")
           ),
           fluidRow(
             plotlyOutput("cumulatedMetrics"))
           )
  )
)

ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
```

I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the white space in `tabName = "Raw Data"`. Remove it and this works.